# getting "org.apache.http.conn.httphostconnectexception connection to http://x.x.x.x:88/mobile.php refused

Tags: php, android, mysql

I've setup a MySql server using xampp, I am creating an android app to connect to the database.  I can connect without a problem using MYSQL Workbench and ODBC connector from off site and ably to push/pull data without errors.   when connecting with the EMULATED phone I am getting "org.apache.http.conn.httphostconnectexception connection to http://x.x.x.x:88/mobile.php refused" in the DDMS.  Any idea why this is happening???

Allow Internet wasn't turned on... it is now , just verified, cleaned and relaunched, now I am getting "ClientProtocolException".

```
public void getData() {
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ///external ip address not local host or trying inside a local network
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://x.x.x.x:88/mobile.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log.tag", "Error in http connection  " + e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Could not connect to Database");
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                isr, "iso=8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log.tag", "Error converting result  " + e.toString());
    }
    try {
        String s = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s + "User :" + json.getString("UserName");
        }
        resultView.setText(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log.tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure you have the INTERNET permission in your Manifest?

Comment: Make sure that the server firewall is not blocking. or maybe antivirus is.

Comment: Server firewall nor the router is blocking, can get through with ODBC and MYSQL Workbench, Internet permissions was not added, it is now.  Now I am getting "ClientProtocolException".

Comment: try using `httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");`

Comment: after the line `HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://x.x.x.x:88/mobile.php");`

Comment: thanks, that changed the error to: android.os.NetworkOnMainTreadException

Comment: ok great, the NetworkOnMainThread is a well-known exception in Android, you will find [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) very useful in resolving this exception

Comment: now all you have to do is to run this code in a separate thread.

Comment: You can ask a new question for the new error, but for this question please accept my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to make this work:

1. Add INTERNET permission to your Manifest
2. Make sure no firewall or proxy is blocking from server side
3. add `httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");` after `httpPost` declaration